# add layer in extjs , openlayers

Tags: javascript, extjs, openlayers

i am working with extjs and openlayers for trying some web application.
now i want to create a coordinate bookmark which click than take this coordinate...

but first of all, it  must create a layer in which name is "Bookmarks"..when you click on it ita take to the this coordinate...

how can add a layer  in which name is "Bookmarks" and how can i go taking coordinate from map...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you will need a *vector* layer to display the bookmarks:

```
var my_bookmark_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    "Bookmarks",    
}, {
    displayInLayerSwitcher: true
});
map.addLayer(my_bookmark_layer);
```

This will add an empty layer which You can use later on.

To get a coordinate from the map, see [this example](http://www.openlayers.com/dev/examples/click.html) in the OpenLayers example folder.
Then you will need to store the coordinate as a feature in the bookmark layer.

Hope it helps :)